# How to remove file associations with IDEA?

Tags: file-association

OS - Windows 7 32-bit. Command `assoc .java=` does not help. I have deleted IDEA. Now I need to delete **ALL** file associations with IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch regedit or any other registry edit application
2. Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in the registry
3. Search ".java" under this key.
4. Click on this key and delete the (Default) value